# OneDrive messing with my windows explorer (On windows 11)

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, onedrive

I bought a new computer that I connected to using my microsoft account. Unfortunately, this synchronized it directly to my OneDrive, which is messing with my file explorer and my OS quite badly.

I uninstalled OneDrive and deleted the folder manually from `C:\Users\noure\Onedrive`, but this is creating problems, as the folder comes back.

For example : In the left pane of my explorer, the `Documents`, `Images`, etc... are pointing towards `C:\Users\noure\OneDrive\Documents`, they should be pointing towards `C:\Users\noure\Documents`, when I try to change it I get the error "Can't move the folder because there is a folder in the same location that can't be redirected. Access is denied."

How do I reset this sidebar? How do I remove the usage of OneNote from my file system? I really don't want to have to perform [a factory reset](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085) for something like this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: “How do I remove the usage of OneNote from my file system?” - Move your Documents and Desktop folder out of your OneDrive folder. You can do this by disabling synchronization of those folders from within OneDrive. In order to do that you will of course have to reinstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert the shell folder locations to default, open OneDrive and do the following:

*Important: Before proceeding, copy the files in those special folders to another folder or external drive. Please don’t copy them anywhere under Desktop/Documents/Pictures. This is because disabling OneDrive backup for a folder erases the local copies of the files. Copying them to a different location beforehand will ensure that you don’t need to download them again from the OneDrive cloud.*

- Right-click the OneDrive icon in the Notification area and click Settings.
- Select the Backup tab, and click Manage Backup
- In the Manage folder backup dialog, click on the Stop backup link under the special folder (Desktop, Documents, or Pictures)
- Click Stop backup in the confirmation dialog that appears.
- Repeat the step for each shell folder you want to revert to the original location.

**See also**

- [Error “The folder can't be moved here” Moving Documents/Pictures, Caused by OneDrive](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-folder-cant-be-moved-here-documents-pictures-onedrive/)
- [Libraries are placed in onedrive folder instead of local folder - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/libraries-are-placed-in-onedrive-folder-instead-of/08909b57-cbf7-4a57-9546-833d154f141c)

Answer (score 1):

You should spend time looking at Sync settings (Control Panel) and Edge Sync.

Turn these down or OFF

I have been using Windows 11 for 18 months, turned all this OFF.

Nothing syncs (unless I demand so) and I did not have to uninstall anything.

There is more than one or two settings so do review all.

One thing more to suggest: If you have documents you do not want synced at all, move to a folder completely outside of One Drive. Then you can have a few documents synced if you so wish, and other documents that will never be sync'd.  Just some organizational thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall OneDrive (download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/download)), And remove your folders from the backup list. This will release the folders from OneDrive's clutches and return it to its right place.
Or you can check out [this post on microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-liberate-my-documents-folder-from-onedrive/2cce0a9d-49af-4ea4-a555-87693df4a2b4) for a more complicating solution.